# Formatting any string to be comma delimited

Tags: java, regex

I would like to format any string to a comma delimited format. Basically, any combination of whitespaces (1 or more) EXCEPT a single space should be replaced by ", ".

Here's my current method:

```
private String formatCommaDelimiter(String text) {
    text = text.trim();
    text = text.replaceAll("(\\S)(  +|( *[\\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]+ *)+)(\\S)", "$1, $4");
    text = text.replaceAll(",+", ",");
    return text;
}
```

It's working perfectly except for single characters (e.g. "a \n b \n c"). Any idea how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Anirudh for putting me on the right track!
I figured it out:

```
text.replaceAll("\\t|\\n|\\x0B|\\f|\\r|\\s{2,}", ", ");
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply do this

```
text.replaceAll("\\t|\\n|\\x0B|\\f|\\r| {2,}", ", ");
```

`\s` is similar to `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`

Comment: It does not work with "a\nb". No single space, but a single new line is ok.

Comment: So basically the right answer would be `text.replaceAll("\\t|\\n|\\x0B|\\f|\\r|\\s{2,}", ", ");` Thanks.

Comment: @mblitz to be more clear `text.replaceAll("\\t|\\n|\\x0B|\\f|\\r| {2,}", ", ");`

Comment: @Anirudh No. Because two consecutive line breaks should be replaced as well. ANY combination of 1 or more whitespaces, except a single space.